# Проблема с записью в MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

В ходе работы программы получаю массив `arr` на 1000 значений, хочу записать в базу, используя PDO

выводит: `Warning: Error while sending QUERY packet. PID=8448`

```
foreach ($arr as $v => $k){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (value, key) VALUES (:value, :key);
    $data = [
        ":value" => $v;
        ":key"   => $k
    ];
    $db->query($sql,$data);
};
```

Так же пробовал разбить по 25 и 50 запросов:

```
$sql = "";
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    $i++;
    if ($i % 50 == 0){
        $db->query($sql);
        sleep(5);
        $sql = "";
    }
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO table(link,price) VALUES ('" . $k . "','" . $v . "'); ";
}
$db->query($sql);
```

выводит:

`Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away in ....\Connection.php on line 53`

Класс Connection:

```
....
public function query(string $sql, array $data = [])
{
    51 set_time_limit(0);
    52 $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);
    53 $sth->execute($data);
    54 $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    55 if (false === $result) {
        return [];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

По итогу в базу ничего не записывается. Пробовал с меньшими значениями (~70-80) всё залетает нормально, помогите решить проблему. Openserver MySQL 5.5 PHP7

UPDATE:
Ошибку `MySQL server has gone away in ...` решило небольшое дополнение к классу подключения:

```
$this->link = new \PDO($dns, $config['***'], $config['***']);
$this->link->query("SET wait_timeout=9999;");
```

`query("SET wait_timeout=9999;");`

Comment: [похожий вопрос без принятого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/482124/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-500-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85)

Comment: вы зачем запрос подготавливаете каждый раз? его надо один раз подготовить, и N-раз выполнить. И что вы оттуда фетчить собираетесь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для повышения производительности Вы можете использовать один INSERT с несколькими VALUES:

```
INSERT INTO table (x,y,z) VALUES(1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3);
```

А то так у вас формируется столько же запросов, сколько элементов в массиве.

INSERT и VALUES нужно также делить на блоки! И больше 1024 записей в один INSERT добавлять не стоит

```
function placeholders($text, $count=0, $separator=","){
    $result = array();
    if($count > 0){
        for($x=0; $x<$count; $x++){
            $result[] = $text;
        }
    }

    return implode($separator, $result);
}
```

By @HerbertBalagtas

```
foreach($arr as $k){
    $arrValues = array_merge($arrValues, array_values($k));
    $sumParams[] = '('.placeholders('?', sizeof($k)).')';
}
```

В запросе в VALUE, подставляйте знаки вопроса '?'.

```
"INSERT INTO table(link,price) VALUES " . implode(',', $sumParams);
```

После этого, $arrValues подставьте в execute($arrValues)

Comment: вы уж добавьте тогда, что все имеющиеся данные в 1 запрос пихать тоже не стоит. По крайней мере в MS SQL есть ограничение на 1000 вставляемых строк

Comment: @teran безусловно! Insert и Values нужно также делить на блоки!

Comment: @Daniil, а как будет выглядеть такая же разбивка для UPDATE?

Comment: а никак. разве что замените ее на `insert...on duplicate key update`

Comment: @Александр в UPDATE можно сделать ОДИН РАЗ prepare() и после выполнять различные execute(). Если это вам как-то поможет

Comment: @Александр И как написал teran, делать fetch после insert не нужно!

Comment: @Daniil, не подскажите как реализовать в prepare? он у меня используется, но как запихнуть все изменения не понимаю